# C++17 call static method of a template class without angle brackets

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17, you can omit angle brackets `<>` when declaring an instance. But why are they still needed when calling a static method from a template class ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T = void> struct A
{
    static const int i = 10;
};

int main() {
    A a; // compile
    int i = A::i; // does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the scope operator works only on classes, namespaces and enumerators... `A` is neither of those things

Comment: You're not calling a method, you're reading a member variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the language feature ([Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)) only dealt with constructing objects. It's based on overload resolution with constructors and deduction guides.

With static data members, it would be an extremely limited feature - it could only possibly work if all the template parameters were defaulted, at which point you're only ever saving two characters (since `A::i` could only ever deduce to `A<>::i`).

With static member functions, it could hypothetically be more interesting (since member functions could suit the same purpose as constructors), but it would complicate scope lookup since you'd have to basically do that step at every scope.

But in any case, CTAD only works with constructing objects because that was the problem it was trying to solve, and it's the only problem it addresses.

Comment: "*CTAD only works with constructing objects because that was the problem it was trying to solve*" It's not just that; it makes no sense to have "template argument deduction" in a context where nothing is being called, and therefore there are no arguments to apply some deduction rules for.

Comment: The goal was litteraly to save two characters, nothing is lost. So what I've understood is that it could be done, be not needed. I was trying to simplify and hide the complexity (the fact that the class is templated), but I will just use another class name. Thanks.

Comment: It creates an annoying dichotomy: the same thing could be A and A<> and not every app programmer has deep insights into c++ variants. It is too late to do anything now about it.